# Databricks - How to pass accessToken to spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I would like to use databricks to run some custom SQL by below function, May I know how to add the "accessToken" as properties?

```
mssql_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX.database.windows.net:XXX;database=XXXXX"

connectionProperties1 = {
  "accessToken" : access_token
}

driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
connection = driver_manager.getConnection(mssql_url,connectionProperties1)
connection.prepareCall("EXEC sys.sp_tables").execute()
connection.close()
```

It return:

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method getConnection([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
```

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using the java sql driver manager in python? Couldn't you use Python equivalents?

Comment: Because pyspark in python cannot run insert/update/delete statement, I make reference from this link: https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/issues/21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `DriverManager` doesn't have the function that accepts HashMap that is created from Python dict - it has the [function that accepts Properties object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-).  You can create instance of properties object the same way as you get `DriverManager` instance, and then pass this object to the `getConnection` function:

```py
mssql_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXX.database.windows.net:XXX;database=XXXXX"

connectionProperties1 = {
  "accessToken" : access_token
}

# create Properties object from the Python dict
props = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()
props.putAll(connectionProperties1)

driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
connection = driver_manager.getConnection(mssql_url,props)
```